# Appium code generates "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, async-await, appium

I have been following the [Appium tutorial](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/index.html) on the official website. After following the steps and adapting their code template to the resource names/paths on my machine, I ran the test.js file using node.js and got the following error:

```html
/home/samaraassis/Appium_tutorial/test.js:18
const elementId = await client.findElement("accessibility id","TextField1");    client.elementSendKeys(elementId.ELEMENT, "Hello World!");
                  ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:684:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:17)
```

This is the content of the test.js file:

```js
  1 // javascript
  2 
  3 const wdio = require("webdriverio");
  4 
  5 const opts = {
  6   port: 4723,
  7   capabilities: {
  8     platformName: "Android",
  9     platformVersion: "8.0",
 10     deviceName: "Nexus 5X API 28",
 11     app: "/home/samaraassis/ApiDemos-debug.apk",
 12     automationName: "UiAutomator2"
 13   }
 14 };
 15 
 16 const client = wdio.remote(opts);
 17 
 18 const elementId = await client.findElement("accessibility id","TextField1");    clie    nt.elementSendKeys(elementId.ELEMENT, "Hello World!");
 19 const elementValue = await client.findElement("accessibility id","TextField1");
 20 await client.getElementAttribute(elementValue.ELEMENT,"value").then((attr) => {
 21 assert.equal(attr,"Hello World!");
 22 });
```

Is the issue really the definition of the client.findElement() function, or is the problem less obvious and I just can't see it? Is there a work-around to make the tutorial work, like using another node.js version? My version is v11.6.0.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is: you cannot `await` an `async` function except from within *another* `async` function. Since you've got a `.then()` clause, just get rid of the `await` keyword.

Comment: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/sample-code/javascript-webdriverio/test/basic/ios-basic-interactions.test.js is almost the same code as the simple tutorial that you have done, but shows the correct invocation pattern.

Comment: I have to say, the Appium tutorial is terrible. It can easily turn potential users away.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your as below. (Note the the code in Tutorial does not match the Demo app at all. Seems nobody is maintaining the tutorial...). The test will click on button "Text" so you will see the next screen.

```
const wdio = require("webdriverio");

const opts = {
    port: 4723,
    capabilities: {
        platformName: "Android",
        platformVersion: "9",
        deviceName: "Pixel 2 API 28 Pie",
        //app: "ApiDemos-debug.apk",
        app: "https://github.com/appium/appium/raw/master/sample-code/apps/ApiDemos-debug.apk",
        automationName: "UiAutomator2"
    }
};

(async () => {
    const client = await wdio.remote(opts);

    console.log(client.findElement);

    const field =   await client.$("~Text");
    field.click();
})();
```

Screenshots
[image]

[image]